# How to use map_df() on a selection of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This code takes a dataframe and applies the prettyNum-Function to every Column:

```
test <- mtcars %>%  map_df(., ~prettyNum(.,big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
```

No i want to select the columns that are given to the function, but i fail to understand how the code has to be. That´s my best guess:

```
test <- mtcars %>%  map_df(., ~mutate_at(.vars = vars(drat,wt), .funs = prettyNum(.,big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")))
```

How can i get the second code working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `purrr::map_df` for this task:

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mtcars, prettyNum, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")

dplyr::mutate_at(mtcars, .vars = vars(drat, wt), prettyNum, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
```

The above does not work because `purrr` is for lists. A data frame is a list of equally sized vectors. Using `purrr::map_df` tears your data frame apart and passes vectors to `dplyr::mutate_at`, which however expects a data frame. This is also the reason why it worked in the first example: `prettyNum` needs a vector which you provide.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!